# Transition effect like the start menu tile transition on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, tiles, windows-phone, transition

I would like to recreate the transition effect which can be observed when a user clicks on a tile on the start menu. But I have hit a road block in my quest. I am unable to search for information related to that particular transition. Is it possible to do so in you own application? If so, please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call it  a 'peel animation' and have implemented it here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/metro-in-motion-part-2-peel-animations/

Others call it a 'turnstile' and have also implemented it:

http://turnstile.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks. Turnstile is what I was looking for. :)

Comment: @MilanAggarwal cool - please remember to upvote / accept as a appropriate. Have fun!

Comment: done. I was waiting for time to elapse as I could not accepted it at that time. Enjoy :)